# Show that $\mathcal H_0 \cap \mathcal H_1 \neq (0).$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Let $\mathcal H_0$ and $\mathcal H_1$ be closed subspaces of $\mathcal H$ with $\dim \mathcal H_0 + \dim \mathcal H_1 \gt \dim \mathcal H.$ Then show that $\mathcal H_0 \cap \mathcal H_1 \neq (0).$

For finite dimensional case it is fine. Because for finite dimensional case Hilbert space dimension coincides with the vector space dimension and if the result fails to hold then $\mathcal H_0 \oplus \mathcal H_1 \subseteq \mathcal H,$ which contradicts the hypothesis.   How to tackle it for infinite dimensional case? If $\mathcal H$ is infinite dimensional then by the hypothesis it follows that $2 \dim \mathcal H \gt \dim \mathcal H.$ This strict inequality can only hold if $\dim \mathcal H \lt \infty.$ Hence according to me it turns out that if the given hypothesis holds then $\mathcal H$ has to be a finite dimensional Hilbert space. Am I missing something?

Comment: How do you define dimension for an infinite dimensional space? If that's just $\infty$, what does it mean to assume $\infty + \infty > \infty$?

Comment: @Andrea Marino this is an exercise given by our instructor. The context I am using it says that every Hilbert space admits an orthonormal basis i.e. an orthonormal system that is total. The dimension a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ is given by the cardinality of any of the orthonormal bases for $\mathcal H.$

Answer (score 1):

I think you're more or less there, though you should explain where the $2 \dim \cal H$ inequality comes from.

It should be emphasized that it is possible to have strict inequalities between transfinite numbers (there are strictly more real numbers than integers), but not between such a number and twice itself.